# JPA Query With Pagable Result Throws Exception (Says not Pageable it should be)

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following query for my JPA application against Postgres DB:

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM Cacl c WHERE c.name LIKE 'caclId%'")
public Page<Cacl> getCaclIdStartsWith(@Param("caclId") String caclId);
```

When I start the application I get the following exception:

```
Error creating bean with name 'caclRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter! Offending method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page .repositories.CaclReposit...(I'm masking here on purpose)... ory.getCaclIdStartsWith(java.lang.String)
```

The implication is that the result would not return multiple records. However it should return multiple records. In fact when I run SQL equivalent query:

```
 SELECT * FROM TBL_CACL WHERE NAME LIKE 'SOME_CACL%';
```

, it works fine and returns multiple rows as I would expect. I assume I am doing something wrong with my syntax but not sure what. Grateful for any insights. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your exception explicitly says: *java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Paging query needs to have a Pageable parameter!*

So, you should correct the method signature in this way:

```java
@Query("SELECT c FROM Cacl c WHERE c.name LIKE :caclId || '%'")
public Page<Cacl> getCaclIdStartsWith(@Param("caclId") String caclId, Pageable pageable);
```

and then to access the second page of `Cacl` by a page size of 20, you could do something like the following:

```java
Page<Cacl> cacls = repository.getCaclIdStartsWith("test", PageRequest.of(1, 20));
```

See also [this section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.special-parameters) of the documentation.